# In git, is there a simple way of introducing an unrelated branch to a repository?

Tags: git, branch

While helping a friend with a git problem today, I had to introduce a
branch that needed to be totally separate from the `master` branch.
The contents of this branch really had a different origin from what
had been developed on the `master` branch, but they were going to be
merged into the `master` branch at a later time.

I remembered from reading John Wiegley's [Git from the bottom
up](http://ftp.newartisans.com/pub/git.from.bottom.up.pdf) how
branches are essentially a label to a commit that follows a certain
convention and how a commit is tied to a tree of files and, optionally
to parent commits. We went to create a parentless commit to the
existing repository using git's plumbing:

So we got rid of all files in the index ...

```
$ git rm -rf .
```

... extracted directories and files from a tarball, added those to the
index ...

```
$ git add .
```

... and created a tree object ...

```
$ git write-tree
```

(`git-write-tree` told us the sha1sum of the created tree object.)

Then, We committed the tree, without specifying parent commits...

```
$ echo "Imported project foo" | git commit-tree $TREE
```

(`git-commit-tree` told us the sha1sum of the created commit object.)

... and created a new branch that points to our newly created
commit.

```
$ git update-ref refs/heads/other-branch $COMMIT
```

Finally, we returned to the `master` branch to continue work there.

```
$ git checkout -f master
```

This seems to have worked as planned. But this is clearly not the kind
of procedure I would recommend to someone who is just getting started
using git, to put it mildly. **Is there an easier way of creating a
new branch that is entirely unrelated to everything that has happened
in the repository so far?**

Answer (score 591, accepted):

There is a new feature (since V1.7.2) which makes this task a little more high-level than what's in any of the other answers.

`git checkout` now supports the **`--orphan`** option. From the [man page](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-checkout.html):

`git checkout [-q] [-f] [-m] --orphan <new_branch> [<start_point>]`

> Create a new *orphan* branch, named
>   <new_branch>, started from
>   <start_point> and switch to it. The
>   first commit made on this new branch
>   will have no parents and it will be
>   the root of a new history totally
>   disconnected from all the other
>   branches and commits.

This doesn't do *exactly* what the asker wanted, because it populates the index and the working tree from `<start_point>` (since this is, after all, a checkout command). The only other action necessary is to remove any unwanted items from the working tree and index. Unfortunately, `git reset --hard` doesn't work, but `git rm -rf .` can be used instead (I believe this is equivalent to `rm .git/index; git clean -fdx` given in other answers).

---

**In summary:**

```
git checkout --orphan newbranch
git rm -rf .
<do work>
git add your files
git commit -m 'Initial commit'
```

I left `<start_point>` unspecified because it defaults to HEAD, and we don't really care anyway. This sequence does essentially the same thing as the command sequence in [Artem's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1384325/in-git-is-there-a-simple-way-of-introducing-an-unrelated-branch-to-a-repository/1384336#1384336), just without resorting to scary plumbing commands.

Comment: Do you know if it is possible to create an orphan branch that stays visible when you checkout any branch from the other "tree"?

Comment: @JJD: I think what you want is git merge.  `( git checkout master && git merge --no-commit "orphan-branch" )`  Some similar tricks will work using git-reset or playing with the index.  But it depends on your desired workflow.

Comment: @Matthew Here is the [changelog for git 1.7.2](https://raw.github.com/gitster/git/master/Documentation/RelNotes/1.7.2.txt).

Comment: @phord I more or less thought of the orphan to contain things like unit tests or documentation separated from the source code of the project.

Comment: @JJD: The script I gave should give you what you want, unless I misunderstood you. When you said "stays visible", do you mean the files will remain in the working directory even though you checked out a different branch?  Using `--no-commit` on `git merge` will achieve this.  You may need to follow up with a `git reset origin/master` so your next commit goes where you want, but then the files from your orphan-branch will show up as "untracked files" unless you also include them in your .gitignore file.

Comment: @phord Thank you. I created an [article that sums up the discussion](http://weblog.avp-ptr.de/20111009/how-to-create-an-independent-branch-in-git/).

Comment: Can you clarify how to push the new orphaned branch to a new remote without including the (potentially massive) history of the original branch please

Comment: how do i make an orphan branch in another directory ?

Comment: GitHub now recommends this solution when [creating a `gh-pages` branch manually](https://help.github.com/articles/creating-project-pages-manually/), as well.

Comment: @chris Can this orphan branch be accidentally pushed to other branch suppose if i am on orphan branch and try to push on master will it create a problem.

Comment: @tcovo how do you remove the still-existing-on-disk files?

Answer (score 37):

From [Git Community Book](http://book.git-scm.com/5_creating_new_empty_branches.html):

```
git symbolic-ref HEAD refs/heads/newbranch 
rm .git/index 
git clean -fdx 
<do work> 
git add your files 
git commit -m 'Initial commit'
```

Comment: Next answer is better for modern versions of git.

Comment: @kikito: Re: "Next answer is better" ... The ordering here on SO is not stable. Could you add a link pointing to what you think is a better answer.

Comment: I was referring to http://stackoverflow.com/a/4288660/312586. You are right, I should not have said "next". It had less score than this answer when I commented.

Comment: `rm .git/index` is ugly :-)

Comment: This one works better for case "I want to commit to the branch, creating it if it did not exist before"

Answer (score 32):

Although the solution with `git symbolic-ref` and removing index works, it might be *conceptually cleaner* to create **new** repository

```
$ cd /path/to/unrelated
$ git init
[edit and add files]
$ git add .
$ git commit -m "Initial commit of unrelated"
[master (root-commit) 2a665f6] Initial commit of unrelated
 1 files changed, 1 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 foo
```

then fetch from it

```
$ cd /path/to/repo
$ git fetch /path/to/unrelated master:unrelated-branch
warning: no common commits
remote: Counting objects: 3, done.
Unpacking objects: 100% (3/3), done.
remote: Total 3 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
From /path/to/unrelated
 * [new branch]      master     -> unrelated-branch
```

Now you can delete /path/to/unrelated

Comment: In my opinion, a clean concept would involve an option to `git branch` or `git checkout`. I'm glad that git makes this sort of stuff possible, but why shouldn't it be easier?

Comment: Because it is, and should be a rare thing. If you have unrelated things branch, it usually belongs to unrelated repository, instead of stuffing it in existing one (although there are exceptions).

Comment: +1. For fellow git newbies, you can apparently then list the branches via `git branch` and switch between them via `git checkout BRANCH_NAME`.

Comment: Thanks for this, I wouldn't have thought about it on my own. This is extra helpful because it maintains the history (if there is any) for the other repo.

Answer (score 27):

In recent Git versions, 2.27 at least, this can be cleanly achieved with the `switch`command:

```
git switch --orphan <new-branch>
```

Official documentation: https://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-switch

Comment: Does this still require cleaning up the index/worktree like `checkout --orphan` does? The docs (currently) don't say.

Comment: AFAICT if should just work.

Answer (score 21):

The currently selected answer is correct, I would just add that coincidentally...

This is actually exactly how github.com lets users create Github Pages for their repos, thru an orphaned branch called `gh-pages`.
The pretty steps are given and explained here:

https://help.github.com/articles/creating-project-pages-manually

Basically the git commands to set this up are as follows:

1. `git checkout --orphan gh-pages` (create a parentless branch called gh-pages on your repo)
2. `git rm -rf .` (removes any files from branch working tree)
3. `rm '.gitignore'` (even the gitignore)
4. Now add website content (add index.html, etc) and commit and push.
5. Profit.

Note you can also [designate a /docs folder](https://help.github.com/articles/configuring-a-publishing-source-for-github-pages/) on you repo to be the source of the "Project Site" that Github uses to build the website.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 13):

[Github](http://github.com) has a feature called [Project Pages](http://pages.github.com/) where you can create a particular named branch in your project to provide files that will be served by Github. Their instructions are as follows:

```
$ cd /path/to/fancypants
$ git symbolic-ref HEAD refs/heads/gh-pages
$ rm .git/index
$ git clean -fdx
```

From there you have an empty repository which you can then add your new content to.

Answer (score 5):

Sometimes I just want to create empty branch in project instantly then start doing work, I will just excute following command :

```
git checkout --orphan unrelated.branch.name
git rm --cached -r .
echo "init unrelated branch" > README.md
git add README.md
git commit -m "init unrelated branch"
```

Answer (score 4):

If your existing content was already committed, you now (Git 2.18 Q2 2018) can extract it into its own new orphan branch, since the implementation of "`git rebase -i --root`" has been updated to use
the sequencer machinery more.

That sequencer is the one now [allowing to transplant the whole topology of commit graph elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50555740/6309).

See [commit 8fa6eea](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8fa6eea0ffd271f0564048dc939987e9640efca5), [commit 9c85a1c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9c85a1c29c5ac26c94aa6eda8da9bbfbc6751785), [commit ebddf39](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ebddf393964120628f60f6f5e435cde87cc209c6), [commit 21d0764](https://github.com/git/git/commit/21d0764c823bdca78b99dae562ca9e5c2a121738), [commit d87d48b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d87d48b2e033e8a8d39afbe7cb5eea331bbe47a6), [commit ba97aea](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ba97aea1659e249a3a58ecc5f583ee2056a90ad8) (03 May 2018) by [Johannes Schindelin (`dscho`)](https://github.com/dscho).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit c5aa4bc](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c5aa4bccb5ffcc01e45915c00d2fce30ce959dab), 30 May 2018)</sup>

> ### sequencer: allow introducing new root commits
>
> In the context of the new `--rebase-merges` mode, which was designed
>   specifically to allow for changing the existing branch topology
>   liberally, **a user may want to extract commits into a completely fresh
>   branch that starts with a newly-created root commit**.
>
> This is now possible by inserting the command `reset [new root]` before
>   `pick`ing the commit that wants to become a root commit. Example:

```
reset [new root]
pick 012345 a commit that is about to become a root commit
pick 234567 this commit will have the previous one as parent
```

> This does not conflict with other uses of the `reset` command because
>   `[new root]` is not (part of) a valid ref name: both the opening bracket
>   as well as the space are illegal in ref names.

Answer (score 3):

Creating a separate repository worked well for me. Didn't have to worry about a <start_point>.

1. Create an new empty repo somewhere else.
2. Rename the master branch to anything other than master, ie `gh-pages`
3. Start your orphan work.
4. Commit your work to a the only branch in the new repository.
5. Push the new branch to the same remote repo that contains the original master branch.

This method is mentioned on:

- https://gitlab.com/tortoisegit/tortoisegit/-/issues/1090#note_77403778
- https://gist.github.com/chrisjacob/1086274/382ef1ccc22b57b9b1f0e3a362b39e806b9ba04c

Answer (score 0):

Found this script at http://wingolog.org/archives/2008/10/14/merging-in-unrelated-git-branches and it works very fine !

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e

if test -z "$2" -o -n "$3"; then
    echo "usage: $0 REPO BRANCHNAME" >&2
    exit 1
fi

repo=$1
branch=$2

git fetch "$repo" "$branch"

head=$(git rev-parse HEAD)
fetched=$(git rev-parse FETCH_HEAD)
headref=$(git rev-parse --symbolic-full-name HEAD)

git checkout $fetched .

tree=$(git write-tree)

newhead=$(echo "merged in branch '$branch' from $repo" | git commit-tree $tree -p $head -p $fetched)
git update-ref $headref $newhead $head
git reset --hard $headref
```

Comment: I believe that the same effect can be achieved using `git fetch $REMOTE $REMOTE_BRANCH:$LOCAL_BRANCH`. Am I missing something?