# How to create a branch without adding all the existing files?

Tags: git

When I create branch in git, all the created files are added to the new branch.

How can I create a branch without adding all the existing files?

Comment: If you are looking for a completely independent branch (no shared history and no common files), then this question is a duplicate of [“In git, is there a simple way of introducing an unrelated branch to a repository?”](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1384325/in-git-is-there-a-simple-way-of-introducing-an-unrelated-branch-to-a-repository).

Answer (score 85):

```
git checkout --orphan branchname
git rm -rf .
```

After doing that you can create, add, and commit new files and the resulting branch will have no common history with any other branches in your project (unless you merge them at some point).

Comment: @XuqiciAcerto Because it has no parents.

Comment: Why do you need to do `git rm -rf` on an orphan branch? The `git log` is showing nothing anyway (`fatal: bad default revision 'HEAD'` to be precise).

Comment: The fact that this is a `checkout` option instead of a `branch` option is frustrating.

Comment: After creating an orphan branch, is it possible to create pull request to that branch? It seems bitbucket show unrelated branch, so you can't create a pull request :(

Comment: @SamarPanda Did you found any solution to create pull-request from such a branch ?

Answer (score 2):

[From the Git Book](http://book.git-scm.com/5_creating_new_empty_branches.html)

```
git symbolic-ref HEAD refs/heads/newbranch 
rm .git/index 
git clean -fdx 
<do work> 
git add your files 
git commit -m 'Initial commit'
```

Comment: Or did you want an orphan branch?  In that case, see the answer by Arrowmaster. Though, the "--orphan" option was only added in 1.7.2.

Answer (score 2):

The current answers are correct, you'd need an orphaned branch, but I would just add that coincidentally...

This is actually exactly how github.com lets users create Github Pages for their repos, thru an orphaned branch called `gh-pages`.
The pretty steps are given and explained here:

https://help.github.com/articles/creating-project-pages-manually

Hope this helps!