# Putting a separate Eclipse project in the "example" folder of a GitHub project

Tags: eclipse, apache-flex, actionscript-3, git, github

I have one Eclipse Workspace containing two projects.
 - The first is my actual library.
 - The second is example code for using the library.

When I push this code to GitHub, I don't want two separate projects, I want the example code to go into an "example" folder of the second library.

How and where would I do this? From Eclipse, GIT, or GitHub?

Or is there a better way of including sample code in GitHub projects? (the example code doesn't actually need any version control)

What if I decide to add more than one sample project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After more experience with Git and GitHub over my belt, now days I usually place any example code in [a separate orphaned branch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4288660/617937).

This has several benefits over placing examples into a sub-folder. Primarily, any changes or additions to the examples (Which obviously aren't critical to the library) won't give unnecessary notices of the library code being "changed", or even "ahead" of code in any forks. Also, this setup works well with Eclipse, since both projects will then have their own separate local repositories.

*It's also a good idea (and I often forget) to point out this "example" branch in the README.*

Answer (score 0):

You can apply source-control to projects in one wokspace, project by project is that pointng to different nodes

Please see Tutorials [Git with Eclipse (EGit)](http://www.vogella.de/articles/EGit/article.html) and [Git, Github and Egit Eclipse integration](http://blog.doityourselfandroid.com/2010/08/14/git-github-and-egit-eclipse-integration/)

Hopes that helps