# gitolite: allow RW users of any repo RW+CD to their personal branch, disallow others

Tags: git, gitolite

In gitolite, I'd like to grant all *write* allowed users of any repo to RW+CD to their personal branch. In other words: Whoever is allowed to RW a project should be allowed to create branches, but only in their personal namespace.

I understand that I can basically do this like this:

```
    repo    some-repo
            RW+CD   = admin
            RW  = foo frob
            R   = bar
            RW+CD dev/USER/ = foo frob #admin
```

but that means that I would have to essentially duplicate the user list for every repo. While this is okay for a small amount of repos it definitely gets ugly once the number of repos or users rises.

I thought about something like this:

```
    repo    @all
            RW+CD dev/USER/ = @all
```

But that seems to give at least read access to *all* users on *all* projects, even if they wouldn't have read rights there otherwise.

What is the best solution for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution would be to manage those branches within individual repo per user, using [wildcard repo or "wildrepo"](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite/blob/pu/doc/wildcard-repositories.mkd):

As detailed in "[user gitolite doc](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite/blob/pu/doc/user.mkd)":

> Note that "`CREATOR`" is a reserved word that gets expanded to your `userid` in some way, so the admin can literally add just the first two lines, and every authenticated user now has his own personal repo namespace, starting with `pub/<username>/`

The first two lines mentioned here are:

```
repo pub/CREATOR/..*
    RW+     =   CREATOR
```

Once that is done, any user can:

- add another repo as a remote
- import (fetch) the branch of his choice in a new **orphan branch** (see "[In git, is there a simple way of introducing an unrelated branch to a repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4288660/6309)",
- Read/Write in that branch.
- push back to the initial repo if he/she is allowed to.