# How to add additional parents to old git commits?

Tags: git, git-rewrite-history

I have a project containing two branches: master and gh-pages. They are essentially two different projects, where the gh-pages project depends on the master project (and not vice versa). Think of it as "master contains the source code, gh-pages contains the binary built from those source files". Periodically, I take the changes that have accumulated in master and make a new commit to the gh-pages branch with the commit message "Bring into line with master commit xxxxxxxx."

[image: how the network graph currently looks]

After a while of doing this, I realized that it would be nice if the gh-pages commit "Bring into line with master commit xxxxxxxx" actually had xxxxxxxx as its parent in the git repository. Like this (bad MSPaint art):

[image: how it would ideally look]

Is there a way to make the repository look like the second image above?  I know how to make new commits follow this pattern: I can do "git merge -s ours master" (which sets the parents of an otherwise empty commit) followed by "git commit --amend adv550.z8" (where adv550.z8 is the binary file that's actually changing). But does git make it easy to go back in time and add new parents to old commits?

I am perfectly willing to "git push -f" and blow away the current history of my Github repository, once I get my local repo looking right. The question is, *can* I get my local repo looking right?

---

**EDITED YEARS LATER TO ADD:** I eventually abandoned my attempts to make the git history of `gh-pages` look like that; I decided that it was too much work for zero gain. My new practice is to aggressively squash commits to `gh-pages`, because saving those commit messages really doesn't matter in my case. (It's just a long line of "Bring into line with master commit..."s, none of which are historically interesting.) However, if I needed to do this again, I'd listen to the answers that said

```
git merge $intended_parent_1 $intended_parent_2
git checkout $original_commit -- .
git commit --amend -a -C $original_commit
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't go back in time and change existing commits. Even when you do something like `git commit --amend`, you're not actually changing the commit; you're creating a new one at the same place in the tree with all the content from the original (plus your changes). You'll notice that the commit hash changes after the `--amend`, and the original is still present in your repo--you can get back to it with `git reflog`.

On the other hand, you *can* go back in time and create an alternate universe. Essentially, you would go back to your `gh-pages` branch point and recreate the whole thing (with e.g. `git cherry-pick` or something) as a parallel branch. The hashes would change, because the commits are different objects.

(I'm curious why you have your repo set up as separate branches, instead of separate directories in the same branch. It seems like the code -> build process would get tedious.)

Comment: "You'll notice that the commit hash changes after the --amend": Only if the content changes, though, right? Changing the commit log message doesn't seem to change the hash, and I'm hoping that changing the parents won't either.

"why separate branches": That's just how GitHub does their "GitHub Pages" feature, which I'm using to host http://quuxplusone.github.com/Advent/play-550.html. You create a new branch named "gh-pages", and whatever's in there is automatically mirrored to the live web page. It's kind of weird, but I think it makes a certain amount of sense under the circumstances.

Comment: "Essentially, you would go back to your gh-pages branch point and recreate the whole thing": I'd be okay with this. But how do I preserve the timestamps of the original commits? I don't want to lose them. That's why I asked how to go back in time.

Comment: I get a new hash even with a `commit --amend -C` with an empty index.

Comment: Now that I think more about it, if you're just trying to preserve the ancestry information, would it make sense to skip the merge parent idea and use tags instead? You could throw annotated tags on the `gh-pages` branch with the `master` commit parent for old commits, and use your merge/amend system going forward.

Comment: I was wrong; the commit hash depends on a timestamp, and `git commit --amend` changes the timestamp. [This project](https://github.com/vog/beautify_git_hash/commits/master) uses that fact to clever effect. 
I don't *think* tags solve any problem I care about. Notice that all the commits to `gh-pages` *already* contain their would-be parents' hashes in the commit message. I specifically want that information to be reflected in their actual parent-set as well, for reasons that are purely aesthetic.
Off-topic: SO's markdown doesn't have any way to insert paragraph breaks?! That sucks.

Comment: The commit hash covers everything having to do with that commit.  The content, the parent reference, the comment, the date/time.  If you change one single bit in a commit, a new hash will be generated.

Comment: @Quuxplusone See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26050327/how-does-git-commit-amend-work-exactly/26050416#26050416

Answer (score 22):

```
git replace --graft $commit $parent1 $optional_parent2
```

```
git replace --graft $original_commit \
    $(git show --pretty=%P $original_commit) \
    $additional_parent
```

Explanation:
[git replace --graft](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-replace) allows to respecify which are the parents of a given commit. This works by writing a new commit with the respective alterations and writing a replace ref that causes git to look up the new commit instead of the original one whenever it is accessed.

`git show --pretty=%P $original_commit` just lists the original parents.

Comment: This is [nearly] the right answer. Nearly, because I had to use `git show --pretty=%P $original_commit | head -n1` — my git (2.11.1) did output a lot more than just parent line.

Comment: this is a message from the apocalyptic future to say that you've both made my life a heck of a lot simpler and i'm very grateful

Comment: Use `git show --pretty="format:%P" --no-abbrev-commit --no-patch ${original_commit}` to avoid `head -n 1`

Comment: Note that parents added this way won't show up on Github

Comment: @wrongusername Do you know if there is a way to make them show up in github?

Comment: @Emoun I ended up just `reset HEAD~1` to delete the commit, and then do a new merge commit from scratch

Comment: I found out using `git filter-branch $original_parent..HEAD` will make the graft permanent and therefore also show up in Github. Caveat: the commit I was adding a parent to was the latest (HEAD) and I only added 1 parent to a commit that only had 1 original parent.

Answer (score 10):

These are your magic words:

```
git merge origin/master --strategy ours
```

Execute this in the `gh-pages` branch in order to record the relation to `master` without actually changing anything. This worked for me when I created the `gh-pages` branch as `--orphan`, as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4288660/946850).

You can even `--amend` this empty merge commit afterwards in order to introduce the changes you actually want to make to your "pages". See https://github.com/krlmlr/pdlyr/network for an actual example on GitHub.

Comment: This, combined with information added to the question in an edit (re `git commit --amend -a -C ...`, etc.) proved useful for me.  Thanks.

Comment: This needs an `--allow-unrelated-histories` flag to work now, as git no longer allows unrelated histories to be merged by default since Git 2.9

Answer (score 1):

@rumpel gave the right answer. Allow me to share the snippets that I use.

First, I've created orphan `master` branch:

```
git checkout --orphan master
git commit --allow-empty -m 'Init'
```

My use case is slightly different, the site I want is in `_site` directory on `develop` branch. Therefore I do:

```
git checkout master
git rm -rf .
git read-tree develop^{tree}:_site
git checkout -- .
git commit -m "Update from develop SHA1:$(git rev-parse --short develop) ($(git log -1 --format=%cd develop))"
git replace --graft @ $(git show --pretty=%P @ | head -n1) develop
```

Note that in last command, I had to filter by `| head -n1` since my `git` output a lot more than just parents.

Comment: Use `git show --pretty="format:%P" --no-abbrev-commit --no-patch ${original_commit}` to avoid `head -n 1`

Answer (score -1):

You can rewrite the commits, but it requires rewriting the entire branch starting from the first commit that needs an additional parent up to the branch tip. Is is (like with rebases) a new branch that just has the same contents.

The trick is to use commit-tree, which takes everything (committer/author info, timestamps, commit message, list of parents), albeit in a rather unpractical way. A bit of scripting does the job then.

Comment: You'd get an upvote if your second paragraph wasn't so bizarrely vague.

Comment: I know. But it is a bit of work, and I don't need that script right now.