# How to add a orphan branch in smartgit

Tags: git, smartgit, orphan

I need to create an orphan branch, which has no parent. How do I do it in Smartgit?

Need some guidance on this..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is one instance where, if SmartGit doesn't support the orphan option from the GUI, you could as well use the CLI (command-line interface) and type a quick:

```
git checkout --orphan newbranch
```

(as in "[In git, is there a simple way of introducing an unrelated branch to a repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4288660/6309)")

Commit at least one file (still through the GUI):

```
git add afile
git commit -m "a first commit in orphan branch"
# no push here, this is purely a local operation in your local repo
```

Then you go back in SmartGit and your new (orphan) branch should be there.

Comment: i did what you said-> but cannot see the branch in SmartGit

Comment: @lakesh I suspect because you need to make at least one commit in that new orphan branch.

Comment: this commit is thru CLI or Smartgit?

Comment: @lakesh through CLI (`git add afile`, `git commit -m "first commit"`), since that branch is not yet visible through SmartGit.

Comment: committing just pushes it to staging, doesn't push it to origin right? this is because, I am worried that it might affect the files in the repository.

Comment: @lakesh a commit doesn't push anything. If you are on your new branch, you will just create a commit on that new branch (in your local repo). No push is involved.

Comment: now can see the branch...Now i can add the new version of the code and commit and push normally.. am i right?

Comment: @lakesh great, I have added the first commit in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: you are correct...Now i can add the new version of the code and commit and push normally.. am i right?

Comment: @lakesh yes, once the branch is visible in SmartGit, it is back to business as usual.