# Git - Start over while preserving old work

Tags: git

I apologize if this is trivial but I've spent the better part of the night searching for a solution and I'm a bit stuck.  I've been using Git for version control of a project for which I'm currently the only developer, and after spending a bunch of time working with a given bunch of code, I'd like to start from scratch in my master branch but "archive" all of my previous work in the current master branch and others within my existing repository.  I currently have a bunch of commits in the master branch followed by a second series of commits in branch A; it looks something like this:

```
                 A: C4-C5-C6
                   /
master: C0-C1-C2-C3
```

I'd like to prepend an empty commit to the project (my current initial commit is not empty), store my current history in a set of branches preserving the hierarchy, and then start working off of that empty commit with new code.  That would look something like this:

```
                     A: C4-C5-C6 
                       /
   oldcode: C0-C1-C2-C3
           /
master: C0' (empty)-C7...
```

I hope that that makes sense, I get the sense that I'd need to some rebasing but I'm not exactly sure how that would work and I don't want to lose what I already have by accident.  Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

---

**EDIT:** It just occurred to me that I could potentially just <s>clone</s> copy the current master branch to a new branch to an old branch, commit, and then wipe my working directory in the master branch and commit again.  This preserves the actual time-line and my old code, and is probably more "proper".  Does that make sense?  It would look something like:

```
                 A: C4-C5-C6
                   /
master: C0-C1-C2-C3-C8(empty)-C9...
                   \
           oldcode: C7
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's probably many ways to do it, but I'd do it like this (based on your diagram):

On your current `master` branch, do `git checkout -b oldcode` <-this creates and checks out a new branch named `oldcode` based of off your current master branch. 
(So at this very moment since you *just* created `oldcode`, it and `master` will be the same. You can confirm this by running `git diff master oldcode`)

Next, just go back to your `master` branch by just doing `git checkout master`.

Now you can just do any commit on your `master` branch to make it diverge (be different) from the `oldcode` branch.

That easy.

You really shouldn't code or "work" on your master branch, that way you avoid having to do this. Or avoid potentially having bugs that make it into your production environment/live code. Branch off the master branch into "topic" branches that you code on and then integrate/`git merge` your changes back in to master once your're done I... Hope this helps!

Comment: @orenyk I just saw ur edit, which basically is on the right track. But forget about the word "clone" as you might get confuzed... since `git clone` is for cloning entire repos. Nothing to do with "copying" branches.

Comment: This worked great, thanks!  I modified the original post so as not to confuse future readers (in terms of clone / copy), but this accomplished effectively what I wanted in my edit above.

Answer (score 1):

Since git 1.7.2, you can use `git checkout --orphan <new_branch_name>` to create branches that don't share any history with existing branches. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4288660/492364) has details on how you can use it. So, just rename all your existing branches using `git branch -m`, then 
use `git checkout --orphan` to create the new ones.

Comment: Thanks for this; I wanted to keep the original hierarchy but I can definitely see where this could be useful.