# Change branch without any commit

Tags: git

I can work as a "branch" without any "commit" in the "`master`" branch.

I'm in this branch.

```
branch master
```

And I want work in the branch "`newStyle`"

**Question**:

**Is it possible (and if yes, how) to switch to that "`newStyle`" branch if I never committed in `master` first?**

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Sorry for the closed question. The moderators, while well-intentioned and generally awesome, preferred not to edit your question and just closed it. I tried to add a question: let me know if it fits your original intent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is called an [orphan branch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4288660/6309):

```
git checkout --orphan newStyle     # only in git1.7.2+
git rm -rf .                       # if you want to start from scratch
<do work>
git add your files
git commit -m 'Initial commit'
```

See also an example in [this article](http://weblog.avp-ptr.de/20111009/how-to-create-an-independent-branch-in-git/).