# Backup then reset master branch with git?

Tags: git, github

I have a git repository (on github) that has the first state of a project which was started then abandoned by its first developer.

We are some to have decided to take back this project, but we agreed not to start from the previous code, because it does not match exactly what we plan to do and was not so developed.

So it's a start from scratch, but I would like to keep a track of what as been done by our predecessor, so we can refer to it if needed. The ideal would be to have a git repository with our `master` branch we are working on currently, and a `old-dev` branch, split from `master` at the initial commit, tracking the old version of `master`.

After reading these pages ([renaming your master branch](http://www.dmo.ca/blog/20080307124544/) and [how to create an empty branch](http://bitflop.com/document/116)), I tried to use `git branch --orphan new-dev` to create a new branch and replace `master` with this one after having moved it to `old-dev` using `git branch -m master old-dev`. But then `git` behaves strangely, making an initial commit copying old `master` and then having me removing everything.

How can I do what I'm trying cleanly, to have a `master` branch totally clean of old stuff ?
Maybe by creating a new repository and importing the old one ? Or are there so tools one github that can help me ? I'm not sure how to proceed...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mention in "[In git, is there a simple way of introducing an unrelated branch to a repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4288660/6309)", `git checkout --orphan` "doesn't do exactly what the asker wanted, because it populates the index and the working tree from `<start_point>` (since this is, after all, a `checkout` command)"

So a cleaner solution would be to **[create your new `master` branch in a new git repo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1384723/6309)**, and then import that branch in your current repo (where `master` was renamed, and where there is not a `master` branch yet)

```
$ cd /path/to/repo
$ git fetch /path/to/unrelated master:master
```

That way, your `master` branch starts from a clean history.

Answer (score 0):

```
git checkout old_master -b
git checkout master
rm [all the old directories and files but not .git mind you]
git add -u .
gir commit -m "Brave new world"
```

You will now have the old code in the branch old_master and a clean directory.

Comment: Sure, but doing that, I keep the whole commit history of old dev in master branch. My problem is getting rid of this history.