# Git branch another branch from current branch

Tags: git

Your current branch is master and if u create another branch like that git branch develop,then in branch develop you will have similar code about master。how can i get an empty branch.

Comment: What exactly is an "empty branch" in your book and what does this have to do with Android? :)

Comment: There's no empty branch. You could branch off the initial commit at best, but I don't see why would ever want to do that. Maybe you just want another repository?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an orphan branch, which start without parent, and will be effectively "empty".

```
git checkout --orphan develop
```

This is since git 1.7.2: see "[In git, is there a simple way of introducing an unrelated branch to a repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4288660/6309)".

Comment: thanks a lot.this is absolutly