# Change git initial commit to kill history

Tags: git

I have a repo where I want to delete all the commits before one commit with the purpose of changing the initial commit of the repo.

I've created a branch with its last commit as the commit I want as the new root:

```
git checkout -b newroot SHA
```

Then I've created a new commit for the initial commit:

```
git checkout -b initial $(echo "Kill history" | git commit-tree $(git write-tree))
```

Then I want to rebase master on top of initial starting from commit SHA, so I did:

```
git rebase --onto initial newroot master
```

But the rebase does not succeed. I get conflicts after applying some commits. Maybe I'm not understanding something but the way I see it, I shouldn't get any conflicts since I just want to apply all the commits of master on top of that new "fake" initial commit.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need an orphan

```c
git checkout --orphan newroot master~10
git commit -m 'Kill history'
git cherry-pick master~10..master
git branch -d master
```

[In git, is there a simple way of introducing an unrelated branch to a repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1384325)

Comment: I still get conflicts when doing that, so my initial commands where also correct. I need to figure out why I am getting conflicts, solve them and see what happens.