# add git branch with completely new files

Tags: git

I have been struggling with this for a while now and was wondering how to add a branch with new files.

It seems simple and it is not an ssh key problem as I can add and edit other branches without problem and am an owner on the repo.

Although I get:

```
fatal: 'XXXXX' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'add a branch'? Do you mean create the branch or push the branch? That error is saying that you didn't connect to a remote repository, nothing about a branch. What command did you run?

Answer (score 0):

Reminder: creating a new folder (like '`XXXXX`') isn't the same as creating a new branch.

If you want a new branch with new files, ie a completely new content, you can:

- remain in your git repo (where there are files already)
- create an **orphan branch** (a branch with no commit parent, so its content will be empty)

  ```
  git checkout --orphan newBranch
  ```

(See more at "[In git, is there a simple way of introducing an unrelated branch to a repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4288660/6309)")

- add your files there (you will see that the working tree is empty in that new orphan branch)
- commit and push

  ```
  git push -u origin newBranch
  ```