# Git delete remote branch and move branch off master, and push remotely

Tags: git, git-branch, git-push, remote-branch

I am on local master `branch` and created subbranch.
I then tried to push it, so that others can access to this branch and work on it too, but it failed. 
Then I thought I should create a remote branch, so I ran

```
git push origin subBran
```

The branch was successfully pushed to remote; however, the branch is not *off* `master`, but *parallel* to `master`...

What command(s) should I use to have the subbranch *off* `master`, and then push to remote?

I think I want remotes/origin/master/subBranch

Current status:

```
$ git branch -a
* subBranch
  master
  remotes/origin/subBranch
  remotes/origin/jc_some5
  remotes/origin/master
```

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4288660/758446

Comment: @BlackVegetable : Hi, could you help providing some commands please? I did research but some are not very related. I was worried that trying randomly would mess up the branches... Thanks so much.

Comment: It sounds like you've done this correctly. What do you mean by "parallel to master"?

Comment: Branches are not children of one another. Your expectation of `.../master/subBranch` is incorrect.

Comment: @isherwood : Hi, thank you for your reponse, I want it to be off master. Because previously, it was remotes/origin/subBranch instead of remotes/origin/master/subBranch  Thank you.

Comment: Further, you'll notice that your local branch is not listed as `master/subBranch` either.

Comment: @isherwood : Oh, thanks for pointing that out. My confusion is, then how do I know subBranch is branched off master please? Thank you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3161204/find-the-parent-branch-of-a-branch

Comment: @isherwood : So what I did was correctly? I was confused because master and subBranch are both under directory of origin. Thank you.

Comment: You can't have branches named `master` and `master/subBranch` in one repository - `master` has to be either branch or directory name, not both. Also, branches in git are just references to commits, and their names aren't related to content in any way.