# Two parallel independet branches in the same repo in git

Tags: git, version-control

I am new to `git` and I am trying to learn some new stuff.

I want to know is it possible to have two branches which are independent of each other (no common ancestor) in the same repo.

**Illustrative Example:**

Let's imagine we have a repo stored in `git@git.someDomain.com`. Under `~/git/` I have many directories (`myDir1`, `myDir2`, `myDirN`...) holding code which I have obtained doing:

1. `git clone git@git.someDomain.com:my-repo-1`
2. `git clone git@git.someDomain.com:my-repo-2` and so on...

Now I want to move `~/git/myDir1/scripts` to `~/scripts/` because I want to keep those scripts separate from the source code stored in `~/git/myDir1`

I go to `~/scripts` and execute `git init` thus I create a local repo for those scripts.

And there I get stuck.

**Questions:**

1. How do I push this local repo to `git@git.someDomain.com:my-repo-1` ?
2. How do I get the content of `~/scripts` (the newly pushed branch) in the `~/someScripts` on my other PC?

I apologize beforehand if I have abused with the git terminology, I am still trying to learn what a branch, remote, origin etc. mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> is it possible to have two branches which are independent of each other in the same repo.

In the *same* repo, that is called an [**orphaned** branch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4288660/6309), but that is not what you are doing in your question.
You are trying to split a repo in two, removing a folder history from one repo (`~/git/myDir1`, folder `scripts/`)and importing its history in a second new repo (`~/scripts`)

> How do I push this local repo to `git@git.someDomain.com:my-repo-1` ?

```
cd ~/scripts
git remote add origin git@git.someDomain.com:my-repo-1
```

But you will need to have at least one commit before being able to do a `git push -u origin master`

For that, see [**Splitting a subfolder out into a new repository**](https://help.github.com/articles/splitting-a-subfolder-out-into-a-new-repository/)

> How do I get the content of `~/scripts` (the newly pushed branch) in the `~/someScripts` on my other PC?

One solution is to **[compress your `~/scripts` into one file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2545784/6309)**, a bundle, copy it to your other PC and clone from that [`git bundle`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-bundle).
That seems easier (as a quick win) than trying to launch a listener on your other PC (git daemon, sshd, httpd) in order to `git push` from one PC to the other: simply copy one file.

Comment: can't I get  _the content of ~/scripts (the newly pushed branch) in the ~/someScripts on my other PC_ by doing some `git clone` operation?

Comment: If both PC see each other, with for example a shared folder, then yes, a git clone is possible.

Comment: what will be the name of the orphaned branch for `git remote add origin git@git.someDomain.com:my-repo-1` , how can I name it, for example, "scrtipts"