# Rewrite Rails 3 to Rails 4 what to do with Git repo

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, ruby-on-rails-4

If I have an old Rails 3 app and I wanted to rewrite the entire thing from scratch to Rails 4.2 (not upgrade); is it recommended to delete everything on the git branch and run the `rails new myapp` generator again?

Or should I just create a new repo for the rewrite?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, you could always do a new repo.

Another option would be to move the branch which was master (i.e. the Rails 3 branch) to something more specific (/old/master or /rails3). Then you can create a new master branch which has your Rails 4 code.

Some info on how to do the new branch: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4288660/1554635

Realistically it comes down to your branches, plans for the Rails 3 version and how many other developers will be using the repo.