# Git to create unrelated branch in a new directory

Tags: git, github, version-control

I tried out [In git, is there a simple way of introducing an unrelated branch to a repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1384325/in-git-is-there-a-simple-way-of-introducing-an-unrelated-branch-to-a-repository) but could not find any correct solution.

What I exactly want is to create a new branch, say `v2`. The branch `v2` will have the contents of the `master` branch but should be independent of the `master`. Also the `v2` branch should be in a separate directory.

My current local directory is :

```
|light-mvc
| --master // contains the master branch
| --v2    // should contain the v2 branch
```

and my remote repo is https://github.com/YashKumarVerma/Light-PHP-MVC (if it matters)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this.

Assuming right now you have only `master` folder inside `light-mvc` and is up-to-date with your remote.

Now make a branch using `git branch v2`. Then `git checkout v2` and make a new directory `v2` and put whatever code you want to put into it. Then push on the same branch ,i.e., `v2`.

So essentially your master branch has `master` folder and v2 branch has `master` + `v2` folder.

I hope this solves it.

Comment: do i have to run `git checkout branchname` inside the `master` folder

Comment: `error: pathspec 'v2' did not match any file(s) known to git.` : when runnign `git checkout v2` in the master directory

Comment: No, it should be where you initialised git using `git init`. That would be `light-mvc` in your case.

Comment: i did not initialize the light-mvc. I did the `git init` inside master

Comment: You can only track files and directories inside a folder in which you initialised git.

Comment: so shall i move the master's content to `light-mvc`

Comment: You can now do something like this, delete `.git` folder inside master and do `git init` in `light-mvc` and make it uptodate with your github remote.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109295/discussion-between-raptor96-and-yash-verma).