# Make orphaned branch from existing repository?

Tags: git, orphaned-objects

I have a git repository that I have done some testing on and I'd like to include it in the main repository.

I would like to add this as an orphaned branch, because I want to keep it but I don't want to bloat the master branch with my test project.

How can I import the git repository as an orphaned brach? I'd like to keep my commits.

Edit to show it's not a duplicate: I didn't actually care about it being orphaned or anything like that, I just wanted to have a way to merge 2 repositories. The given answer is correct and solves my problem.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand: Do you want to push your tests on the remote repository ? or the opposite, to get the main code from the remote machine to your local repository ?

Comment: They are different repositories, both of them local

Comment: still not understanding… what is the problem about creating a branch with `git checkout -b --orphan test/somefeature && git add . && git commit 'my tests things'` ?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1384325/in-git-is-there-a-simple-way-of-introducing-an-unrelated-branch-to-a-repository

Comment: I want to copy all my commits on my test repository to a new orphaned branch

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you're looking at this wrong.  In fact, the existence of this question implies something that is not true.  I think what you want is more correctly named "disjoint subgraphs".

To get there, bear with me through this next exercise.  If you just want an answer, scroll down. :-)

## Exercise: which branch is orphaned?

Imagine you have some repository, and in this repository there are two branches named `X` and `Y` (no `master`, just `X` and `Y`).  Branch `X` points to commit `a123456` and branch `Y` points to commit `b987654`.  These commits point to their parents as usual, but if we draw the entire commit graph (the repository is small so this fits nicely in this SO answer) we get:

```
o--o--o--o    <-- X

o--o--o---o   <-- Y
    \    /
     o--o
```

There are two different root commits.  Branch `X` points to `a123456` which is the tip of a four-commit chain rooted at `a000000`.  Branch `Y` points to `b987654` which is the tip merge commit of a six-commit structure rooted at `b000000`.

*Which branch(es), if any, is an orphan branch?*

(This is a good place to stop and think about that question.)

---

If you chose `X`, why did you choose that one?  If you chose `Y`, why did you choose that one?  If you chose *both*, I think you could justify that choice; but if you answered *neither*, I would call that correct and note that you have now agreed with Git.

(If you chose both `X` and `Y`, what is your reason for calling these "orphan branches"?  I think you could argue for this as a correct answer, and justify it by saying that neither one is connected to `master`.  If we then added a branch named `master` and made it point to any of the four commits on `X`, you would then say that branch `Y` is orphaned and `X` is not.  If you made `master` point to any of the six commits on `Y`, you would then say that `X` is the orphan and `Y` is no longer orphaned.  There are probably more ways to decide, depending on how twisty you want to get with how you define "orphan".  But that's not what Git means, and in fact, there is better terminology, which will not disagree with Git, and will serve you better in the long run.)

## Disjoint subgraphs

In our exercise example repository above, neither `X` nor `Y` was an orphan branch, because both have commits on them.  In graph theory—Git repositories are built around graph theory—the two branch names `X` and `Y` point to *disjoint subgraphs* of the overall graph.

#### Side note: what Git means by *orphan branch*

In Git, an *orphan branch*, created with `git checkout --orphan newbranch`, is a branch in special state, "yet to be born".  This state lasts until there are commits on the branch, after which the branch is no longer an "orphan branch".  Now it's just an ordinary branch, like any other.

Git actually implements the orphan-branch state in a way that causes the abstraction to leak rather badly.  Specifically, it writes the new branch name into `HEAD`, but nowhere else.  Since `HEAD` contains the name of the current branch, if you check out any other branch, this overwrites the `HEAD` file, and the orphan branch itself vanishes completely.  In other words, only one single branch can ever be in "orphan" state, and it gets there by having its name stored in `HEAD` and only in `HEAD`.  Since `HEAD` stores the name of the current branch, only the current branch can be an orphan.

## At last, the answer to what I think your question really is

Given two unrelated repositories *R1* and *R2*, you want to make a union repository (possibly a new repository *R3*, perhaps just modifying one of the two original repositories) whose commit graph is a *disjoint* graph resulting from the union the two commit graphs in *R1* and *R2*.

Let's make this as a new third repository.  (It's even easier to just glom *R1* into *R2* or vice versa, by omitting some of these steps, so let's start with the full exercise and you can scale it back if you want.)

To build the new repository *R3*, first, create an empty repository:

```
$ mkdir r3 && cd r3 && git init
```

Now fetch everything from *R1* into *R3*.  You can do this by adding *R1* as a named remote (this is almost certainly the way to go if you are adding *R2* into *R1*, though then we're now in *R1* adding *R2* rather than in *R3* adding *R1*).  You could just run `git fetch` and give it a URL and use the branch information that it drops into `FETCH_HEAD`, but let's go with adding both as remotes.  The `<url>`s here can be paths (`../../otherrepo.git` or `/path/to/otherrepo.git`), or `ssh://...` or `git://...` or `https://...`, as usual.

Then, fetch everything from *R2* into *R3*.  We use exactly the same steps, just a different remote name and URL:

```
$ git remote add r1 <url for r1>
$ git remote add r2 <url for r2>
$ git fetch r1; git fetch r2
```

At this point you are essentially done: you have the union as the commit graph in your new repository.  The only thing left to do is to make local branch names pointing to the same commits as some or all of the remote-tracking branches.

Since we named repository *R1* `r1`, all of its branches are in `refs/remotes/r1/branch-name`.  Likewise, since we named *R2* `r2`, all of its branches are in `refs/remotes/r2/branch-name`.  You can refer to these by their shortened versions, `r1/whatever` and `r2/whatever`.  Let's say `r1` has branches `master` and `A` and `r2` has branches `master` and `B`.

Because there is only one `A`, you can do:

```
$ git checkout A
```

and you now have a branch named `A` pointing to the same commit as `r1/A`.  Moreover, your local `A` is set to track `r1/A`: that is, its upstream is `r1/A`.

The same holds for `B`.

You can create a new `master` in `r3` but it can only point to the same commit as *one* of the other two repositories, and you cannot use this shortcut.  Let's say you want `r3`'s `master` to match `r2/master`:

```
$ git checkout -b master r2/master
```

will create it and set it up to track `r2/master`.

If you don't want this upstream `--track` setting, create the branches using `--no-track`.

That is all there is to it: creating these two disjoint subgraphs really is that easy.  You just need to know that this is what you are doing, and that fussing about with `--orphan` is only required if you want to *grow* a new disjoint subgraph organically, rather than fetching it from some existing repository.

Comment: Yes this was what I was looking for! Can I add a remote that is secretly just on my local computer? Or do I need to push it to GitHub and fetch it back to do this?

Comment: The `<url>` part of any remote can be a plain file path (or a `file://` url but why bother? :-) ).