# how can create a new branch from already existing commits?

Tags: git, git-branch, git-commit

I have branch which contains three commits. Now I want to create three new branches of these three commits, each commit should be separate branch, how can I achieve this?

Comment: Should those other branches keep the history? Meaning, do you want one branch with 1 of the commits, the other branch with 2 of them and so forth. Or do you want each branch to only have a single one of those 3 commits?

Comment: I want each branch to only have a single one of those 3 commits

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### About git branches

Reading the question and the comments (from the OP), I believe there is confusion about what a branch *is*, in git. A branch is simply a little sticky note pointing to a commit. Branches are not a "heavy" object in git, so you do not really "create new branches with those commits", nor does it make sense to say that "each commit should be a different branch"; you just label one commit "mybranch1", the other commit "mybranch2" and so on. The commands have been given by @TimBiegeleisen (`git branch <name> <commit>`).

Reading a little primer on how `git` structures its data may help. http://gitready.com/beginner/2009/02/17/how-git-stores-your-data.html

Comment: `nor does it make sense to say that "each commit should be a different branch"` why? If you've worked on 3 separate things on the master branch, but then decide you want to explore each one of those separately, that would make perfect sense.

Comment: I'm (intentionally) splitting words here. A commit *is not* a branch. I have the feeling that the OP is used to other VCSs, where branches are indeed "first class" objects.

Comment: From "I have branch which contains three commits" it sounds like the OP knows that a branch is not a commit.

Comment: Let's just see if he finds this answer useful. :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you want three independent branches, each with a single commit taken from the original branch.

You can do this by creating [orphan branches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1384325/in-git-is-there-a-simple-way-of-introducing-an-unrelated-branch-to-a-repository), and then [cherry-picking](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick) the commits.

For example:

```
git checkout --orphan branch1
git reset --hard
git cherry-pick <hash-of-commit-1>
```

and so on for the other two commits.

Comment: I want to create new branches with those commits each one in each branch

Answer (score 0):

You want to use `git branch` in the following way:

```
git branch branch_name <sha1-of-commit>
```

So since you want three branches from these three commits you should use:

```
git branch branch1 <commit #1>
git branch branch2 <commit #2>
git branch branch3 <commit #3>
```

To find the SHA-1 hashes of the three commits, you can type `git log` on the branch in question.  Inspect the log until finding the three commits from which you want to branch.

Answer (score 0):

Create new branches from the original commit, then `cherry-pick` the commit you want:

```bash
# From the master branch
git branch branch-1 HEAD~2

git checkout -b branch-2 master~3
git cherry-pick master~1

git checkout -b branch-3 master~3
git cherry-pick master
```