# Confusing github graph

Tags: github, version-control

I have found, that in easy way I can create for my github repo web page (using pages.github.com), so I don't thing a lot and I perform all necessary steps to do that.

Everything work, I have my brand new repo website but when I comes back to my repo graph I can see something wierd:

[image]

there is some strange gap in this graph... how I should understand that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That indicates the history of those two branches are unrelated. They have different roots. They share nothing in common except they're in the same repository.

This is normal for Github Pages. It's a branch stored in your repository for your website. It does not contain your code and has no relationship to your code.

Comment: @roher Ah ha! Done.

Comment: how can I create bymyself e.g. from terminal another unrelated branch? do you have maybe some piece of documentation?

Comment: @roher I was just looking at that myself. `git checkout --orphan` apparently. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1384325/in-git-is-there-a-simple-way-of-introducing-an-unrelated-branch-to-a-repository

Comment: Please tell me what is the purpose of creating this kind of branch?

Comment: @roher For exactly what you're using it for. You have two things in the same repository, unrelated in their content, but related that they're for the same project. One is the product, one is the web site about the product. This simplifies publishing, the `gh-pages` branch is completely safe to put on a web server, there's no danger of exposing code. It also simplifies working on the two separate systems, the people working on the project website don't have to sift through the project code. You could also make a separate repo for the web site, this is easier now that there are organizations.