# How to create a new branch without pre-merge remote-tracking commits in Git?

Tags: git, github, version-control

Whenever I create a new branch `(git checkout -b <newBranchName>)`, I use to get many commit logs:

```
Merge remote-tracking branch 'upstream/master' into develop    e53c044

Merge remote-tracking branch 'upstream/develop' into develop   feda328

Merge remote-tracking branch 'upstream/develop' into develop   4bbd301

Merge remote-tracking branch 'upstream/develop' into develop   4dfcfcb

Merge remote-tracking branch 'upstream/develop' into develop   bfaccfb

Merge remote-tracking branch 'upstream/develop' into develop   754c0ab

Merge remote-tracking branch 'upstream/develop' into develop   b0454b0

Merge remote-tracking branch 'upstream/develop' into develop   f96182f
```

[image]

How can I create a branch without such logs?

Comment: Is this question what you asking for? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1384325/in-git-is-there-a-simple-way-of-introducing-an-unrelated-branch-to-a-repository

Comment: Not sure what you're asking here, creating a new branch does not introduce any new commits, those commits (whose messages you see) must already be in your repository. Are they on the branch you branched *from*?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe `orphan` parameter of `git checkout` could help you:

```
git checkout --orphan NEW_BRANCH
```

This will create a new branch named NEW_BRANCH with zero commits on it. But now all files stay in cache area, you could use "git rm --cached ..." to unstage:

```
git rm -r --cached .
```

`-r` here could unstage files recursively.

Answer (score 0):

The commits for the new created branches are based on the parent branch you created from.

Such as if you create a new branch `new` from `develop` branch as below graph:

```
A---B---C   developer
         \
            new
```

When you show the logs for `new` branch, you will find the commits `A`, `B` and `C` are showed.

**If you want to create the `new` branch without showing the parent commits**, you can create an orphan branch (execute on `develop` branch):

```
git checkout --orphan new
```

Then there will have no commits on `new` branch. the commit history will as below:

```
A---B---C   developer

            new
```

**If you want to create the `new` branch with only part of the commits for it's parent branch `develop`**, you can use:

```
git checkout -b new <last commit you want to contain in new branch>
```

Such as if you want to contain only commits `A` and `B` in `new` branch, you can use the command `git checkout -b new <commit id for B>`, then the commit history will be:

```
A---B---C   developer
     \
       new
```

Comment: Thanks! :)
(earlier I was trying "git checkout --orphan -b new" and it was throwing some errors)

Comment: While making PR I'm getting "X and Y are entirely different commit histories."

Comment: You can merge the two related branch by command for first time: `git merge new --allow-unrelated-histories`.

Comment: Can you merge the two branches successful now? Since the two branches has unrelated histories, after merge by command for first time, then you can merge through PR.