# GitLab: GUI Option for Orphan Branch

Tags: git, version-control, gitlab, version

I am trying to create an independent, orphan branch off from the master in GitLab.  I know that we can use git in the git bash command line to create an orphan branch with `git checkout --orphan orphanbranch`.  Working from the GitLab GUI, can you create an orphan branch off from the establish master?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not see such an option from the Gitlab web interface itself.

Plus, an orphan branch usually starts empty.

You could then populate it with the content of the current HEAD of `master` branch of you need to.

If you do so from your cloned repository, then of course, [you can start an orphan branch from any commit you want](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4288660/6309).
But you know that. From the web interface directly though, that does not seem possible.

Comment: How can you populate it with the content of the current HEAD of master via GUI?

Comment: @Cos I don't think there is an easy way to populate and male a new commit directly from the web GUI.