# How is it possible to reset a Git repository to the state before the first commit?

Tags: git

I know that I can go back in history to earlier commits using `git reset --hard <commit>`. However, this only lets me roll back to the first commit (not before the first commit).

I want to do this, since I created a Git repository and committed a lot of wrong files and directories. Simply deleting the repository and starting over is not an option here, since repositories are created by an admin.

How can I reset my Git repository to the state before the first commit?

Comment: Technically, this (`git checkout --orphan`, set up index, make new root commit, proceed) isn't quite resetting to the state-before-the-first-commit as all the *existing* commits continue to exist. However, it's probably what you want. Once all *names* for the old commits that you don't like are gone, those commits themselves will eventually be garbage-collected.

Answer (score 3):

You can do whatever changes you want, and amend to the last commit:

```
# do changes
git commit --amend
# enter a new commit message if you wish
```

If you want to merge two commits, you can use `git rebase -i --root` which allows you to handle the very first commit with the next ones.

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative to amending the first commit, you can also create a fully new branch [using `git checkout --orphan`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1384325/in-git-is-there-a-simple-way-of-introducing-an-unrelated-branch-to-a-repository) and then reset `master` to that one:

```
git checkout --orphan new_master
# add files
git commit -m "new initial commit"
git checkout master
git reset --hard new_master
git branch -D new_master
```

Comment: Nice, it works flawlessly! Could the same be achieved using `git rebase -i`? If no, why not?

Answer (score 3):

```
git checkout --orphan temp      # Start a new history with a dummy initial branch
# Prepare your first commit...
git commit                      # As usual, this will actually create the temp branch
git checkout -B master          # Bring master onto this new commit
git push --force origin master  # Update the remote, dropping the old history
git branch -d temp              # Delete the temporary branch
```