# How can I upload a new github branch to a repository so it can be compared and resolved

Tags: git, github

TL;DR:  I want to upload three un-managed codebases, compare and sort out the best of each, and eventually create a proper git repository with proper branching.

---

I'm very new to git/github. I'm trying to help a group that until now has been managing code through horrible manual syncing practices.

I took the best version of the code from coder #1 with VS Code in a folder, and directly uploaded to github web app  as the master branch.

(I think) now I want to create a second branch as user2, so that I can do comparisons, and  then iron the differences. I do understand normally you would want to create a branch off of the master, and this isnt the normal routine.

But I'm unclear procedurally how I should actually do this. Github on the web has an option to directly create a new branch from dropped files, but I am exceeding size and file limits.

I saw some talk of creating an "orphan" branch, which seemed like a possibility I might want to explore, but it seemed to lead down a rabbit hole.

I am willing to use git / github directly or command lines, but I'm really quite lost. I have downloaded standalone git, and the github app for windows 10, and have both integrated into VS Code.

Comment: I recommend doing all this offline strictly on your machine. There's no need to upload the code to GitHub. It's best to sort all this out on your own and only upload the final result.

Comment: I don't even see what this has to do with Git.

Comment: [In git, is there a simple way of introducing an unrelated branch to a repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1384325/in-git-is-there-a-simple-way-of-introducing-an-unrelated-branch-to-a-repository)

Comment: How large are your files? I ask because you say you're exceeding file size limits and GitHub do have limits on individual files

Comment: @astrochun, small files, bit more than 100 files, which is the upload limit i believe for the web UI.